# nbconvert does not work properly with HTML conversion MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

First I want to point out that every time I `pip3`, everything goes under this PATH `/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin`, that's the same for Jupyter Notebook. If I `which jupyter`, it will give me this PATH `/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin/jupyter`

I have Jupyter kernel installed on VS code as well as a stand-alone web based Jupyter Notebook. The issue is that I cannot use `nbconvert` on both of them. When I say `nbconvert`, I am talking about cannot convert to HTML. Usually when you installed Jupyter Notebook, the `nbconvert to html` should work fine. It's usually the  `nbconvert to pdf` does not work well because you need to install some `latex` tools to be able to run.

Here I will describe what happens when I try to run `convert to html` on both platform.

**Web Based Jupyter Notebook:**

[image]

**VS Code Jupyter Notebook:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'template_paths'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 350, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 518, in convert_notebooks
    cls = get_exporter(self.export_format)
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 102, in get_exporter
    if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 325, in __init__
    super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._init_preprocessors()
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 491, in _init_preprocessors
    conf = self._get_conf()
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 507, in _get_conf
    for path in map(Path, self.template_paths):
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 518, in _template_paths
    template_names = self.get_template_names()
  File "/Users/XXX/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 601, in get_template_names
    raise ValueError('No template sub-directory with name %r found in the following paths:\n\t%s' % (base_template, paths))
ValueError: No template sub-directory with name 'lab' found in the following paths:
    /Users/XXX/Library/Jupyter
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
```

I also run command like `python3 -m jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb` and it comes to the same error as above.

I think they're caused by the same issue, but I don't really know what's the issue here.

Can someone help me out please? Thank you!